# Hook for a new `UI` starting in Vaadin 14

Tags: user-interface, vaadin, hook, lifecycle, vaadin-flow

The [Navigation Lifecycle](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-lifecycle.html) in the Vaadin 14 manual says:

> It is also possible to register a standalone listener for this event using the `addBeforeEnterListener(BeforeEnterListener)` method in `UI`.

But in modern Vaadin with the routing feature, we are no longer supposed to be writing a `UI` subsclass. My rough understanding is that there is indeed a `UI` object automatically instantiated for us, and then routing automatically replaces the content within that `UI` object. So the existence of a `UI` object is supposed to be transparent to us  programmers using Vaadin Flow.

➥ So what is the lifecycle hook on a new `UI` instance so I can write a user-authentication check as a `BeforeEnterListener` to work globally across all my `@Route` views?

Calling [`UI.getCurrent`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/UI.html#getCurrent--) will not do, as I would need to call that from somewhere in my layouts, but I am trying to register a listener *before* my layouts exist.

Comment: **BEWARE** The behavior and purpose of `UI` has changed dramatically in recent Vaadin. The `UI` object is *not* necessarily stable for the entire time your window/tab is open. **`UI` objects are replaced**, inexplicably, and sometimes quite rapidly. You should no longer store window/tab scoped objects on the `UI` object. See the Vaadin Forums for more discussion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To hook into UI init, there is the [`UIInitListener`](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/advanced/tutorial-ui-init-listener.html).

> A `UIInitListener` can be used to receive an event each time a new UI has been created and initialized.
>
> The ideal place to add UIInitListeners would be inside a [`VaadinServiceInitListener`](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-service-init-listener.html)

E.g. with Springboot:

```java
@Bean
VaadinServiceInitListener vaadinServiceInitListener() {
    return new VaadinServiceInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void serviceInit(ServiceInitEvent serviceInitEvent) {
            serviceInitEvent.getSource().addUIInitListener( initEvent -> System.out.println("UI Init for " + initEvent.getUI()));
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: FYI: For real-world use of the `UIInitListener` shown here, see [my thread](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17810577) on the Vaadin Forums.